# No redirecciona en el controlador despues de una llamada ajax en Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Necesito redireccionar a una ruta en el controlador después de ejecutar un Jquey

Tengo el siguiente Jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", "parte_id", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/actualizar_parte",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "id": $('#parte_id').val()
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Y en el controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
def actualizar_parte
    return redirect_to parte_actual_path(params[:id])
end
```

Entra a la acción en el controlador, se queda en un loop corto (lo veo en el log de puma), finaliza, pero no redirecciona a la nueva dirección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las redirecciones (respuestas con status code 302) son interpretadas por el cliente (en este caso, tu browser) para llamar a la nueva url. Por ejemplo cuando haces click en un link y la respuesta desde el servidor viene con un 302, es el browser quien realiza la petición a la nueva url.
No expusiste más detalles de tu lógica, pero para tu caso, donde estás usando `$.ajax`, que viene de una librería externa y tu browser no tendría por qué interpretar las respuestas que reciba, creo que tu mejor opción es manejar la redirección desde la misma llamada xhr:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/actualizar_parte",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        "id": $('#parte_id').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
      if (data.redirect) {
        // Redireccionando a la nueva url
        window.location.replace(data.redirect);
      } else {
        // Lógica para el caso que no venga redirección (si es que hay alguna)
      }
    }
});
```